# How do I access the original Candy Box game?

Tags: candy-box

I know most people are more interested in Candy Box 2 than the first Candy Box game, but I would like to try the original version. Unfortunately, I can find it anywhere and when I look up Candy Box, only the second version of the game pops up. How can I get to the original Candy Box game?

Answer (score 2):

The original Candy Box can be accessed at [candybox2.github.io/candybox](https://candybox2.github.io/candybox/).

There may be some confusion since the URL includes `candybox2` in it, but it's actually the first one.

The second Candy Box game is at [candybox2.github.io](https://candybox2.github.io/)